# In Matlab, is it possible to terminate a script, but save all its internal variables to workspace?

Tags: matlab, save, workspace, keyboardinterrupt

I am running a script, but it is taking much too long so I want to terminate the script. However it has calculated a lot of data which I would ideally not want to throw away. Is there an alternative to `ctrl-C` with which you save the internal function variables to the workspace?

Ideally I'm looking for a *Matlab* keyboard shortcut like `ctrl-C`, but if that really can't be done maybe there is a way to do this in the script of my function. Any idea how to let my script react to `ctrl-C` as well, or maybe a GUI element which I can cancel and then I save the variables through my script?

Some similar questions I have found, but that don't answer my question:

[close/pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475813/close-pause-process-in-matlab)

[terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791144/how-to-stop-a-running-script-in-matlab)

Different question, similar answer:

[dbstop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140476/running-script-stop-in-the-middle)

**EDIT:**

This question is different because the problem the asker has is different: they want to know where the error is, which in my case Matlab already says. I just want to keep all data from working memory when it happens.

Comment: I don't think you can do this: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?383556-Matlab-breakpoint-at-running-function gives some suggestions for the future though. You might consider periodically saving all your variables to a fie, then if you do get into this situation you could view that file after breaking. Doesn't help you today though. But it's a good feature request to send to Mathworks!

Comment: You can't catch ctrl-c in MATLAB. For alternative solutions, maybe this one helps: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246784

Comment: possible duplicate of [running script stop in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140476/running-script-stop-in-the-middle)

Comment: @horchler Although their solution is the same, their problem was not. They basically want to know where an error originates, I want to save the data in working memory when an error arises.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## MATLAB versions 2016a and later

If you are using post 2016a versions of Matlab there is actually a pause button that appears when you run the script (as described by @pedre). This allows you to pause the script, inspect variables and then resume afterwards.

Make sure to check out the next section as this may still be convenient.

## Older MATLAB versions

Actually the trick is to use `dbstop if error`.

First use this, then run your script. Once you introduce an error (for example, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), you then have the chance to inspect/save your workspaces manually.

You will not be able to resume the script.

Comment: After reading a lot of |`you cant do this`|'s, this is a much better answer than I expected, thank you! If I run this as the first command inside the body of a function, will it work as well?

Comment: @Leo I think you can call it any time before the error happens though it feels a bit strange to put debug commands in your regular functions. Personally I found my efficiency to go up significantly after I put this in my `startup.m`. (If there is an error that breaks my code I want to look at it anyway in 99% of the cases).

Comment: You can find these debug options in the GUI as well. Editor > Breakpoints. You can also break on warnings, or set breakpoints at specific locations in your script, and even conditional breakpoints. It is worth knowing how to use these.

Comment: Someone tried edit my post to tell me that the solution 'did not work' for 2015b. I don't have access to 2015b now, but would be very surprised if dbstop if error was suddenly taken out of commission. -- If you feel like this answer is very much incomplete, consider adding an answer so people may get the benefits and review it.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to click inside your script so you can get the `Editor` page open, and then press pause, and see all intern values there.

[image]

Comment: There are many users using old versions of MATLAB (pre R2016a). I suggest you add a note saying that it was introduced in the R2016a release. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36074605/2338750).

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for answering! =) A little note: Sentences such as "I had the same problem..." etc are considered noise, since it doesn't really add any information to the answer. SO is a bit different than many other forums and q/a sites, since it focuses on the problem and answer alone, not the personal aspect. The reason for this is that questions and answers are there for _future visitors_, not the person asking the specific question alone. As an example, starting questions with: "Hi, I have a problem and have tried for 2 hours ...." is just noise for anyone reading the question.

Comment: Since you can't add pictures yourself, I included a screenshot of the pause button. If you don't like my edits, there is a "Rollback" option in the edit section. You can edit the question by pressing "edit" below the answer. Anyway, +1 from me =)

Answer (score 2):

A colleague showed me an alternate way to incorporate this in my function, by attaching a `save()` command to the cancellation of a `waitbar` like so:

```
%appoint emergency file location
emergencysave = char(inputdlg({'fill in here:'}, 'windowtitle', 1, 'c:\defaultstringhere.mat'));

%or just emergencysave = 'c:\emergencysave.mat';



%create some GUI element you can cancel
times = 10;
wbinfo = struct('curlength', {0.0});
wb = waitbar(wbinfo.curlength);
wbinfo.wb = wb;



%attach save() to cancelling
anyimportantvariable = [];
for i=1:times
    anyimportantvariable = [anyimportantvariable, i^2];
    wbinfo.curlength = i/times;
    try
        waitbar(wbinfo.curlength, wb)
    catch
        save(emergencysave, 'anyimportantvariable');
        return;
end
```