# MATLAB: script vs function concerning output-argument

Tags: matlab, function, return-value, workspace

I have a script which might be aborted due to long runtime and continued later. Let's assume it looks a bit like this:

```
data = []; % can't preallocate as I don't know the number of entries yet here...
while(1)
   % ...
   data = [data; someNewEntry];
end
```

The good thing about it is that when running as a script, whenever I abort it, I have the variable `data` in te workspace.

But I wanted to convert it into a function because the script has quite a big amount of variables and clutters up my workspace with it. Let's assume I now converted it like this:

```
function data = myFnc()
data = []; % can't preallocate as I don't know the number of entries yet here...
while(1)
   % ...
   data = [data; someNewEntry];
end
```

Problem nnow is: When I abort the function, I'm losing all the entries in `data` which have been made to this point. How to solve this issue and make return the current vector `data` when aborting the function? The only possible solution I came up with was to use was something like this to use in the for-loop:

```
if(nargout == 1)
   assignin('caller','data', data);
end
```

But somehow I don't like this approach too much. But okay it seems alright to me. But one thing still annoys me about it: When using that I always assign the data to the workspace-var `data` as I don't know how to get the name of the output variable of the caller (i.e. `bla = myFnc()` -> it would be `bla`, thus `assignin('caller','bla', data);`). I know there is the matlab function `inputnames()` but I couldn't find the equivalent for the output vars.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sidenote, if `someNewEntry` is a scalar for instance. You can grow `data` more efficiently by using: `data(end+1) = someNewEntry`

Comment: Thanks for that, but It actually is a vector building up a data-matrix :) But still good to know

Comment: In that case it would be `data(end+1,:) = someNewEntry`.

Comment: Oh didn't know that's faster though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to use global variables. Example with a simple counter:

```
function data = myFnc()

global data; % make it a global
if isempty(data) % not yet initialized
    data = [];
end

i = 1;
while(i < 10)
   pause(1)
   disp(i)
   data = [data, i];
   i = i + 1;
end
```

Then on the command line, you have to do `global data` once, and you can access the saved state. Quick test, I aborted the program with CTRL+C while it was running:

```
>> clear
>> clear global
>> x = myFnc();
     1
     2
     3
     4
Operation terminated by user during myFnc (line 10)
>> x
Undefined function or variable 'x'.
>> data
Undefined function or variable 'data'.
>> global data
>> data
data =
     1     2     3     4
```

The use of global variables is usually not recommended, but on occasion they can be useful. I sometimes use globals to cache an expensive calculation so that it only has to computed once for every time I launch Matlab:

```
global data;
if isempty(data)
    data = expensive_calculation();
end
```

For complex programs, there are probably cleaner ways to save some state from one iteration to another (implement some object?, pass a state object from one iteration to the next?, save to file?), but for some quick and dirty script, using globals is probably the easiest way.

Comment: The only thing about it is: You are also writing to the var named `data` instead of dynamically writing to the variable named like the caller named it :-) That would be a nice thing to have. But okay, at least the global data variable doesn't automatically overwrite the variable `data` that might be existent in the workspace already (as it would when using `assignin()`). So it's also a pretty cool approach :)

Comment: @bjoern Yes, it is better to give the global variable a different name, to avoid overwriting an existing variable.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 recommended solutions:

**1. Interrupt the function without losing the workspace**

As I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19006478/983722), this should not be a problem if you always switch on

```
`dbstop if error`
```

**2. Frequently save your variables**

With your assignin solution you already came close, as it 'saves' the variable to the base workspace. However this is still not a very safe space to store variables. Therfore I would recommend saving them with:

```
save data data
```

If the second option is too much of a performance killer you can just do it every 1000 iterations or so.

Comment: I'm saving it at the end of the script into a file, too :-) But yeah I see your point about the saving. Do you know a way to get the name of the caller's output variable?

Comment: There's a function that gives you the name of the caller's input variable (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html), but I can't seem to find an equivalent for the output variable.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to use a MATLAB reference-type variable. For example, you could use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html), like this:

```
m = containers.Map();
myFcn(m);
% Later, after hitting CTRL-C
m('data') % get latest value
```

with a function like this:

```
function myFcn(map)
data = [];
while true
    data = [data, rand()];
    map('data') = data;
end
```